# How to map the NHibernate Data Model to the Domain Model?

Tags: nhibernate, dns, fluent-nhibernate, datamodel

I started creating a domain model and now I asking myself, how can I map this domain model to a NHibernate Data Model ((using Fluent NHibernate)? Is there anywhere a good and simple example of how to do that?

With Data Model I didn't think about the physical/relational Database Model(!) What I meant was the Data Model in the Data Access Layer. So maybe I should change the term into Data Access Layer Data Model?! I hope some of you can follow me^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start reading the [NHibernate manual](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html), it's not very long and in chapter 5 covers many details about the different options that exist in the mappings. I find also important chapter 6 about collection mapping an 8 about inheritance.

Maybe you can start with [the getting started page](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started) from fluent nhibernate, but to understand all the options you will have to lookup their meaning in the NH manual as Fluent NHibernate assumes that you are already familiar with the XML.

I don't have enough information about [NHibernate in Action](http://www.manning.com/kuate/) but the good old [Hibernate in Action](http://www.manning.com/bauer/) was also useful because the mapping examples for the Java version are in most cases valid on .NET and provides examples and detailed information on each parameter.

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest one for getting started in a step-by-step manner that I have come across 
[Your very first NHibernate application – Part 1](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Your-very-first-NHibernate-application-Part-1.aspx#1052)

However, I would recommend that you simply download the latest binaries from the [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/downloads) download area rather than getting the source from Subversion, installing Ruby and building it locally on your machine but that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, have you tried [www.nhforge.org](http://www.nhforge.org) and http://fluentnhibernate.org/ ? Both have excellent introductory guides.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Getting started](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started) page on the [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) site.  And definitely take a look at the [Auto Mappings](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping) capabilities.  I was up and running in a couple of hours.  Good luck!